# AES Шифрование сообщение без синхропосылки и расшифровка сообщений

Tags: golang, aes, криптография

Какие есть методы для шифровки сообщения без использования синхропосылки, симетричная криптография, реализации на ЯП Golang?

```
Метод:

    Сервер: Шифрует все данные 256 битным ключем
    Клиент: Принимает зашифрованные данные и расшифровывает данные ЗНАЯ 256 ключ.
```

Какие есть режимы шифрования AES без использования синхропосылки?

Comment: что за синхропосылка?

Comment: @Zergatul российский стандарт симметричного блочного шифрования (не знаю как по другому называется, я называю синхропосылка ибо юзается симетричное шифрование)

Comment: Это называется вектором. **IV**.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать инициализирующий вектор?

Comment: @Ninazu Все режимы AES не требуют **iv** в обязательном порядке. **iv** нужен лишь для повышения криптостойкости алгоритма (например, как соль для hash-функций, соль тоже никогда не была обязательным условием работы hash-функций).

Comment: Я синхропосылку (iv) вшивал в клиент вместе с ключом

Answer (score 0):

Вектор можно генерировать из ключа к примеру, если не хотите хранить его отдельно

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/hex"
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "time"
)

//Общие переменные для сервера и клиента
var (
    //Порт сервера
    PORT = ":10010"
    //Ключ для де/шифрования
    KEY, _ = hex.DecodeString("421A69BC2B99BEB97AA4BF13BE39D0344C9E31B853E646812F123DFE909F3D63")
    //Терминирующий байт
    TERM_BYTE = byte(0)
)

func main() {
    //Запускаем сервер в отдельном потоке, чтоб проемулировать удаленную работу
    go server()

    //Ждем 3 секунды пока запустится сервер
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    //Запускаем клиента
    client()
}

//Сервер.
func server() {
    //Слушаем порт
    ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", PORT)
    conn, _ := ln.Accept()

    for {
        //Получаем сообщение в HEX формате
        hexRequest, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString(TERM_BYTE)
        //Преобразовываем строку в зашифрованный массив байт
        encRequest, _ := hex.DecodeString(hexRequest[:len(hexRequest)-1])
        //Расшифровываем сообщение
        message, _ := decrypt(KEY, encRequest)

        fmt.Println("Сервер получил:", string(message))
        //Формируем ответ
        response := append(message, " -> 'Ответ'"...)
        //Шифруем ответ
        encResponse, _ := encrypt(KEY, response)
        //Преобразовываем в строку
        hexResponse := hex.EncodeToString(encResponse)

        fmt.Printf("Сервер отправляет: %s\n", hexResponse)

        //Отправляем ответ обратно клиенту
        conn.Write(append([]byte(hexResponse), TERM_BYTE))
    }
}

//Клиент
func client() {
    //Подключаемся к серверу
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1"+PORT)

    message := " 'Запрос' "
    //Шифруем сообщение
    encRequest, _ := encrypt(KEY, []byte(message))
    //Преобразовываем в строку
    hexRequest := hex.EncodeToString(encRequest)

    fmt.Printf("Клиент отправляет: %s\n", hexRequest)

    //Отправляем запрос на сервер
    conn.Write(append([]byte(hexRequest), TERM_BYTE))
    //Получаем ответ от сервера
    hexResponse, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString(TERM_BYTE)
    //Преобразовываем строку в зашифрованный массив байт
    encResponse, _ := hex.DecodeString(hexResponse[:len(hexResponse)-1])
    //Расшифровываем сообщение
    messageBytes, _ := decrypt(KEY, []byte(encResponse))

    fmt.Println("Клиент получил: " + string(messageBytes))

}

func encrypt(key []byte, message []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    b := message
    b = PKCS5Padding(b, aes.BlockSize)
    encMessage := make([]byte, len(b))
    iv := key[:aes.BlockSize]
    mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(encMessage, b)

    return encMessage, nil
}

func decrypt(key []byte, encMessage []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    iv := key[:aes.BlockSize]
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if len(encMessage) < aes.BlockSize {
        return nil, errors.New("encMessage слишком короткий")
    }

    decrypted := make([]byte, len(encMessage))
    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(decrypted, encMessage)

    return PKCS5UnPadding(decrypted), nil
}

func PKCS5Padding(cipher []byte, blockSize int) []byte {
    padding := blockSize - len(cipher)%blockSize
    padText := bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(padding)}, padding)

    return append(cipher, padText...)
}

func PKCS5UnPadding(src []byte) []byte {
    length := len(src)
    unPadding := int(src[length-1])

    return src[:(length - unPadding)]
}
```

Demo https://play.golang.org/p/0sS2uWjx8Us

Comment: Так тут генерится всё время всё рандомно, мне нужно фиксировано, то есть  я хочу криптануть сообщения "Привет, привет!" и у меня должно выйти допустим 421A69BC2B99BEB97AA4BF13BE39D0344C9E31B853E646812F123DFE909F3D63BD1BC0AE46A1 и когда я буду енкрпитить это сообщение на другой стороне клиента всё равно будет выходить результат "Привет, привет!", то есть что-то типа decrypt(key, []byte("421A69BC2B99BEB97AA4BF13BE39D0344C9E31B853E646812F123DFE909F3D63BD1BC0AE46A1"), )

Comment: А тут так получаеться всё время ключ рандомный, вектор тоже рандомный, всё рандомно, а фиксированого результат нету, а мне нужен именно фиксированый результат ибо как я буду декриптить сообщения на другой стороне сервера не зная ключа (тк как он рандомный)  да ещё и с вектором IV от которого результат енкрипта всё время будет другой.

Comment: Ну так замените key на произвольные 32 байта а не генерируйте случайные. Или сгенерируйте один раз, сохраните и пользуйтесь потом этим ключем. Мне казалось это очевидным

Comment: У меня ключ перегенерировался при каждом деплое автоматически. Чтоб инвалидировать протокол, и принудительно заставить всех пользователей обновить клиент, так как старый становился нерабочим

Comment: всё, заменил, подставил в decrypt сообщение которую нужно декриптунть вместо encMessage, то есть decrypt(key, []byte(" AEF93F7613B880F09D34963F7BC94BCF")), ошибка panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

Comment: @tramway Значит вы что-то напутали если паникует. Обновил пример с Клиентом-Сервером и статическим ключем

Comment: А в чем смысл такого шифрования? Режимы с IV придуманы для безопасности, если у вас постоянный IV, этот дополнительный уровень безопасности ломается. Используйте тогда ECB режим, там нет IV, уровень безопасности будет тот же, как и с константным IV в режиме CBC.

Comment: @Zergatul Вообще я не понимаю в че сложность у @tramway с IV. Возможно он проникнется примером, и поймет что в векторе ничего страшного нет, и будет использовать все таки его динамически для каждого сообщения. К примеру можно брать `iv = hash(encRequest + KEY)`

Comment: @Ninazu вычисляемый IV на основе предыдущего сообщения не лучший вариант. Такое использовалось в старых версиях TLS, потом от него отказались в пользу генерации случайного IV каждый раз и отправкой вначале зашифрованного сообщения.

Comment: @Zergatul. Так я же не предлагаю брать из прошлого, а из хеша текущего с секретной солью (в качестве соли ключ можно использовать, ну либо отдельную соль). Мне это кажется более секьюрно чем отправлять IV в открытом виде, вначале сообщения. Толку тогда от него если он известен. А если предлагаете IV тоже шифровать, то как его расшифровать. Или для шифрования IV использовать упомянутый вами ранее ECB?

Comment: @Ninazu Этот подход еще хуже. Режимы шифрования придуманы для того, что бы когда вы отправляете одинаковые сообщения, злоумышленник не смог этого определить. Хеш сообщения + соль как IV этому не поможет, так как IV получится один и тот же для одинаковых сообщений, и весь шифротекст тоже.

Comment: Так как передать IV безопасно вместе с сообщением? Или ничего страшного что атакующий его узнает?

Comment: @Ninazu В криптографии никогда нельзя полагаться на то, что кажется :) Нужно смотреть на общепринятые практики и не изобретать ничего. Передача IV в открытом виде не несет никаких проблем с безопасностью. К IV есть простые требования, он должен быть уникальным и злоумышленник не должен иметь возможности влиять на его генерацию.